# Reconnection issues with openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

i am using openfire xmpp server and asmack library to implement chat service , the biggest issue that i face is the reconnection problem to the xmpp server.

whenever a connection is made to the xmpp server there are lots of stanza is being exchanged possibly around 5 to 7 stanza in a desktop applicaiton or web application it seems ok , but for mobile application where 3G link is pretty weak , in that case it too good to exchange so much of stanza.

i have tested that when the wifi has a weak signal or 3g link is down , i am making a reconnecting to the server (in background process) but i mostly get a response time out error and taking too much time if the connection gets successful.

i have seen messenger like whatsapp in which they are making a reconnection pretty fast. i want to do something like that only.

i have read about the pre-http binding but its exist in ejabber but didnt find anything in openfire moreover htt-prebinding is for anonymous users and i am using registered users only.

so can anyone tell me how can i reconnect fast to the xmpp server.

while exploring i saw xmpp protocol XEP 0198 to resume the streaming session but it seems openfire doesnt support this so can anyone tell me what is the better and faster way to reconnect to the openfire server when network link goes down.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your openfire version is too old,the newer is supported for session resume,by the way asmack is deprecated you can switch it to smack.here is github address:
https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack.git